# I have problem in JqGrid in mvc asp.net

Tags: jqgrid

I am working on jqgrid.And I need to display records same as in database tables.
Suppose there is 2-3 spaces in a particular item , so it should be display like this. I dont want to remove this space in my jqgrid.

Exp: Display like this-         Jqgrid        is good feature
but its displaying -              Jqgrid is good feature
without space() I want to display,If there is 2 space or more we need to display with all the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- Add a jqGrid formatter (or modify your server-side code) to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`
- Add a jqGrid formatter (or modify your server-side code) to enclose the data within a `<pre>` tag - this will preserve formatting but unfortunately will also change the font, which is probably not what you want. But maybe you can figure out a way around that problem.